# How do I attach a material/texture to an IFC object?

Tags: texturing, materials

I have installed the BlenderBIM addon with the hope that I will be able to render IFC models that I make using Tekla Structures.
I managed to come a long way learning how to work with Blender and add materials and textures to native Blender objects with success, only when I apply the same methods to the IFC object the base color does change but the texture doesnt render on the IFC object.

In the image below you can see that the Blender native sphere object renders the texture but the IFC object only displays a brownish color. The IFC object is a concreet wall so originally its color was gray and the material profile came out of the IFC data, I then removed the concreet material from the wall and instead assigned the planks texture which again changed the base color of the object but the texture does not render.

I am under the impression that the IFC once imported into Blender might have some "super" material that overrides all other assigned materials or perhaps I just don't get any of this.

I followed a few BlenderBIM specific videos that deal with materials but couldnt find information that specifically deals with assigning textures to the IFC materials. Furthermore it doesnt help when every Blender version in videos looks different then what I have on screen (2.93.1) and therefor I am hoping that someone here can guide me with simple steps on how to solve this issue (if possible) :)

Thank you.

[image: My example]

Comment: Hello ! May I suggest you post this question rather directly on the addon github issues https://github.com/IfcOpenShell/IfcOpenShell/issues or alternatively on the OsArch forum https://community.osarch.org/

Comment: Materials in IFC are more complicated than in Blender, as for instance they can include different layers with their own set of properties (eg density, resistance to fire, resistivity, sound suppression, or any custom property really) so it's not as easy as a 1-1 translation between the Blender material and the IFC material

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no texture support in the BlenderBIM Add-on with IFC. Though in theory textures can be supported either through externally referenced material definitions or via UV conventions, this is not something I would advertise to users just yet.

Sorry.